# Mobile Safari Web App Zoom issue

Tags: ios, forms, safari, zooming, hammer.js

I am building a mobile web app that uses jQuery and hammer.js for touch controls. hammer.js has a feature called "prevent_default" which turns off Safari's scrolling/zooming/prettymucheverything. I have a page with a form using < input > for text fields, and a javascript listener that calls .focus() when you tap the form.

This all works well up until a point. The page is fixed in place and looks real pretty, and when you click on a form field it zooms in and the iOS keyboard appears. The problem is that when the user is done entering text, there is no way to zoom out. The browser is so zoomed in from .focus() that the browser bar is gone and you have to close the browser tab and re-type in the URL instead of refreshing.

I am looking for a way to force the browser to zoom out back to the initial view. I've looked all over the internet for some solution but have yet to find anything.

I have the viewport meta tags in the header to disable zooming from the beginning, but is not useful in solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution is to focus and blur an inputfield after you have changed the viewport attributes.

```
function refreshViewportZoom(){
  var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
  viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, scale=0.5, user-zoom=0.5, zoom=0.5');
  document.getElementById('myInputField').focus();
  setTimeout(blurLater,2000);
}

function blurLater(){
  document.getElementById('myInputField').blur();
}
```

The `blurLater` is needed as a function, because Safari seems to look ahead and ignore it otherwise.

Comment: I found this solution that seems to be working well. Only hitch is when Safari tries to zoom in this thing zooms it back out and you get a screen wiggle

https://gist.github.com/2008932