# Reset / change zoom via javascript on Mobile Safari Web App

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

This issue has been discussed here before, however, I don't get the suggested solution to work.

I want to change the scale / zoom of a webpage on a mobile safari via JS. The solution suggested by

- [How can I use JavaScript to set the zoom level on mobile safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502292/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-set-the-zoom-level-on-mobile-safari)
- [Mobile Safari Web App Zoom issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058953/mobile-safari-web-app-zoom-issue)
- [Is is possible to change page zoom in Mobile Safari via Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574189/is-is-possible-to-change-page-zoom-in-mobile-safari-via-javascript)

is to set the "viewport" meta tag.

I tried this, but the scale is not changed.

```
$('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, user-scalable:no');
```

When does safari interpret the viewport setting? Only when loading a page or also when the value is changed programmatically (what I would expect with repsect to the answers of the questions mentioned above)?
Did this behaviour change in some iOS version?

BTW: Where can a find a list of recognized arguments for viewport?

Many thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Which result do you need?